# Databricks SQL API: Load csv file without header

Tags: azure, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I am trying to load a csv file (without header) into a delta table using the [Load the sample data from cloud storage into the table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/databricks/ingestion/copy-into/tutorial-dbsql#step-5-load-the-sample-data-from-cloud-storage-into-the-table) guideline but I can not find any instructions how to define source file schema/header.

```
COPY INTO my_table
FROM '/path/to/files'
FILEFORMAT = <format>
FORMAT_OPTIONS ('inferSchema' = 'true')
COPY_OPTIONS ('mergeSchema' = 'true');
```

Bases on [delta-copy-into](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/delta-copy-into.html#syntax) and [FORMAT_OPTIONS](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/delta-copy-into.html#format-options) docs I assume, the `enforceSchema` would be the right option but how to privide the schema definition using SQL API?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have header in the files then Spark will assign names automatically, like, `_c0`, `_c1`, etc., and put them into the table. If you want give a meaningful names then you need to use slightly different syntax by using `SELECT` option that will give you ability to rename columns, and do type casting if necessary.  Like this (cast just for example):

```sql
COPY INTO my_table FROM (
  SELECT _c0 as col1, cast(_c1 as data) as date, _c2 as col3, ... 
    FROM '/path/to/files'
)
FILEFORMAT = <format>
FORMAT_OPTIONS ('inferSchema' = 'true')
COPY_OPTIONS ('mergeSchema' = 'true');
```

P.S. I'm not sure that `infrerSchema` is good to use here, as you anyway may need to do casts, etc.